# Using FeatureSpacePlot to group similar images

Tags: plotting

First time posting a question here,and I apologize for any breaches of protocol. I welcome any advice that enables me to observe protocol where breached.

I am using Mathematica 13.1 to group images into similar clusters using FeatureSpacePlot[]. The function works as documented, and my images are appropriately grouped. Of course many of them are quite similar. My question: how do I retrieve the filename of the images from their arrangement within the resulting plot? I've struggled with Tooltip and related functionality without success, and without the ability to correlate (programmatically) the images appearing in the generated plot with the image name or filename used to import them, I face a prohibitively time consuming manual mapping of image plotted to image name / filename.

Any help will be abundantly appreciated, and I thank you in advance.

Mathematica code in notebook appears as follows: (apologizes - either I'm obtuse, or directions for pasting formatted code are less that clear, or both)

begin code

```
    images={Import["h:\\jpgs\\_dsc0049.jpg"], Import["h:\\jpgs\\_dsc0050.jpg"], 
    Import["h:\\jpgs\\_dsc0051.jpg"], Import["h:\\jpgs\\_dsc0052.jpg"], 
    Import["h:\\jpgs\\_dsc0053.jpg"], Import["h:\\jpgs\\_dsc0054.jpg"], 
    Import["h:\\jpgs\\_dsc0055.jpg"], Import["h:\\jpgs\\_dsc0056.jpg"], 
    Import["h:\\jpgs\\_dsc0057.jpg"]}
```

FeatureSpacePlot[images]

(* plot proper not included to maintain privacy of those photographed *)

end code

Comment: Have you tried `LabelingFunction -> (Callout[First@Last@#3, Above] &)` with data of the form `{"file_name"-> image, ...}`?